# My Business Q&A API - delete answer returns 404

Tags: google-my-business-api

Migrating from 4.9 to the new My Business Q&A API I'm having trouble upon answer deletion ([method](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/qanda/rest/v1/locations.questions/deleteAnswers)).

My code:

```
    $client = $this->initGoogleClient($refreshToken);
    $gmbService = new MyBusinessQA($client);
    $gmbService->locations_questions->deleteAnswers($question->name);
```

$question->name is in the format of locations/locationID/questions/questionID.

Response is 404, Requested entity was not found yet I can see that this particular answer is live, I'm also retrieving it from the API.

I believe this is either a bug or I'm missing something.

Comment: "I can see that this particular question is live" is not what the error is telling you. It's saying that it could not find an answer by you for that question. Does the question currently have an answer by you?

Comment: @vpriesner yes, it does, I meant answer, I'm going to edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, I can reproduce it.
Please report it to the [Google Business Profile API Support](https://support.google.com/business/contact/api_default).

Comment: Thank you for confirming, I have already sent them a report ticket. Hopefully they will fix this soon!